# Defaults for directive attributes in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

```
<drctv
    (eating)="eating()"
    [apple]="tree"
    [ice]="cone">
</drctv>
```

Given above Code in a template, is it possible to define defaults and only set the attributes when needed?

E.g.

```
<drctv     
    [ice]="chocolate">
</drctv>
```

and the rest of the directives are set to their respective default values either in component, but even better in directive, e.g.:

```
@Input() apple: string = "tree";
@Output() eating = new EventEmitter();
```

Comment: Should just work. What's the problem?

Comment: Somehow "tree" from @Input() gets not set in parent component.

Comment: If you set `[apple]="tree"` then this is overridden by the value of the `tree` property. Hard to see what exactly you try to accomplish without seeing more code.

Comment: Agree, Ok I will add more code a bit later.